# Eclipse: Source locator does not exist: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceLocator.JavaAdvancedSourceLookupDirector

Tags: java, eclipse

For some reason when I imported a new Maven project into Eclipse and went to Run the application, Eclipse gives me the following error:

Source locator does not exist: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceLocator.JavaAdvancedSourceLookupDirector

Things I have tried:
-Deleting the target folder
-Ensuring I don't have two instances of Eclipse running
-Clearing the cache in Eclipse

Has anyone else encountered this particular problem and have advice for how to fix it? Frustrated.

Comment: This might be caused by using a very old Eclipse with a newer version of m2e. Can you reproduce this in the current version of Eclipse? If yes, show a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @arundeepchohan **Never ever delete the `.metadata` folder** since it does not only contain caches but also stuff you don't want to lose! Deleting the `.metadata` is a hoax spread on Stack Overflow and has already caused problems for many. If `-clean` does not help, use a fresh workspace (_File > Switch Workspace_) having its own `.metadata` folder instead. But in this case, I don't think it helps.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.  I ended up downloading the newest version of Eclipse along with using a fresh new Workspace and it seemed to do the trick.  SO RELIEVED.

Comment: For me update the plugins didn't work out. In fact the update stopped for some reason. But I restart the IDE (STS, a variant of Eclipse) couple times, and it eventually seems working fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the 'Oracle WebLogic server tools' plugin then it will work fine.
Go to help>eclipse market place>installed